WatsonX model for a chatbot
So I am looking forward to create a chatbot (eventhough I have used the term chatbot, user doesnot directly gets invloved with watsonX. API calls will be used for the whole process) using IBM watsonX and IBM BAW. IBM BAW will invoke a REST request to the WatsonX and, WatsonX will provide a response (Request would be the question from a customer and that question will be passed to WatsonX and it will provide the response). I need to know the best type of watsonX to this scenario and how to expose watsonX to use as an API to make this possible. Thanks.
enter image description here
I have looked through documentations and found many articles relating to calling watsonx APIs. But not a specific one for this.

So I have resolved this issue using the documenations provided by IBM. My issue was I have used an invalid API key to generate the access token (The access token is only visible when it is created and we can download or copy it. I have used the API key ID to request access token and hence the issue BXNIM0415E) If you encounter the same issues please refer the following documentations.

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-userapikey&interface=ui#create_user_key

also you can use the cURL to invoke the request (Prompt in my case)
